# Принудительное включение полной версии сайта в мобильном браузере

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, вёрстка, cms

Есть сайт, свертстанный на бутстрапе.Десктопная версия готова и причесана, но мобильная еще сыровата, и её как то надо отключить, сделав так, чтобы на мобилках показывался сайт для десктопа. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: наверное убрать meta:viewport надо

Comment: Не надо недоделанные модули кидать в ветку для публикации, тогда не будет таких проблем)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для фиксации ширины экрана используют мета тег viewport.
В теге  нужно прописать

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Где **width=1024** это ваша ширина сайта, а в **initial-scale=1.0** указывается начальный масштаб для окна просмотра на мобильных устройствах